# How to fix UnboundLocalError at /accounts/register

Tags: python, django

I made a registration from for my django app.But when I click on the submit button I'm getting this error:

> local variable 'first_name' referenced before assignment
> Request Method: POST
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register
> Django Version: 3.1.4
> Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
> Exception Value:
> local variable 'first_name' referenced before assignment
> Exception Location: E:\django\Hello_world\accounts\views.py, line 8, in register
> Python Executable:  C:\Users\Asus\Envs\test\Scripts\python.exe
> Python Version: 3.9.0
> Python Path:
> ['E:\django\Hello_world',
> 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.zip',
> 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\DLLs',
> 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib',
> 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39',
> 'C:\Users\Asus\Envs\test',
> 'C:\Users\Asus\Envs\test\lib\site-packages']

My code is

> views.py

```
def register(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':
      first_name = request.POST[first_name]
      last_name = request.POST[last_name]
      username = request.POST[username]
      email = request.POST[email]
      password1 = request.POST[password1]
      password2 = request.POST[password2]

      user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password1, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
      user.save();
      print('user created successfully')
      return redirect('/') 
  else:
      return render(request, 'register.html')
```

and the html file is:

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register" method="post">
    
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="text" name = 'first_name' placeholder="First Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name = 'last_name' placeholder="Last Name"><br>
        <input type="text" name = 'username' placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="email" name = 'email' placeholder="E-mail"><br>
        <input type="password" name = 'password1' placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type="password" name = 'password2' placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is `first_name = request.POST['first_name']`... The same with the other `request.POST`s.

Comment: But you should use a form for validations and cleaning: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put quotes around your dictionary keys. Change your code to this:

```
      first_name = request.POST['first_name']
      last_name = request.POST['last_name']
      username = request.POST['username']
      email = request.POST['email']
      password1 = request.POST['password1']
      password2 = request.POST['password2']
```

Comment: so silly of me :) . although thanks for the help.